# NextAuth returning 401 for localhost API authentication with credentials provider

Tags: reactjs, next.js, localhost, strapi, next-auth

I am building a `NextJS` application and I am using `NextAuth`. The weird part of it is that when I am authenticating via my API which is a domain which is online with `https` it works fine but when replacing it for my `http://localhost:1337` it never even reaches my API. On another device it does work so I am guessing what could cause the problem.

Somebody familiar with this problem?

I am using a `Strapi` API for authenticating. Both `https://` and my `localhost` environment.

So basically the only thing I change is the `const apiUrl`. The rest of my code is the same.

When making the `http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local` in my `Postman` application it does work so the endpoint is reachable but for some reason not for my NextJS application.

This is my `signIn` function:

```
import axios from 'axios';

//const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL_LIVE;
const apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL_LOCAL;

export async function signIn({ email, password }) {
    const res = await axios.post(`${apiUrl}/auth/local`, {
        identifier: email,
        password: password
    })
    return res.data;
}
```

So the `REACT_APP_API_URL_LIVE` works and `REACT_APP_API_URL_LOCAL` doesn't.

This is my `nextAuth`:

```
import { signIn } from "@/services/auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
        name: "Credentials",
        credentials: {
          email: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
          password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
          if (credentials == null) {
              return null;
          }
          try {
              const { user, jwt } = await signIn({
                  email: credentials.email,
                  password: credentials.password
              });
              return {  ...user, jwt };
          } catch (error) {
              return null;
          }
      }
      }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
      session: async({ session, token }) => {
          session.id = token.id;
          session.jwt = token.jwt;
          return Promise.resolve(session);
      },
      jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
          const isSignIn = user ? true : false;
          if (isSignIn) {
              token.id = user.id;
              token.jwt = user.jwt;
          }
          return Promise.resolve(token);
      }
      },
      pages: {
          signIn: '/login'
      }
  };
```

The weird part is that the same configuration is working on another computer.